# Como trocar uma palavra específica de uma frase por outra?

Tags: java

Estou tentando mudar uma palavra de uma frase na qual eu mesmo digito e não consigo.

Meu código...

```
if (op_menu==10){
            System.out.print("\nDigite uma frase: ");
            frase_escrita = in.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("Selecione uma palavra para trocar: ");
            palavra_selecionada = in.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Trocar por: ");
            palavra_nova = in.nextLine();

            fnc.trocar_frase(frase_escrita, palavra_selecionada, palavra_nova, new_frase);
        }
```

função...

```
void trocar_frase(String new_frase, String frase_escrita, String palavra_selecionada, String palavra_nova){
    new_frase = frase_escrita.replace(palavra_selecionada, palavra_nova);
    System.out.println(new_frase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer a substituição de sub-strings dentro duma string a classe [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) oferece dois métodos:

- [`public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))
  Substitui por `replacement` todas as correspondências encontradas, na string, a partir da expressão regular `regex`.
- [`public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))
  Substitui por `replacement` apenas a primeira correspondência encontrada, na string, a partir da expressão regular `regex`.

Tomando como exemplo a frase do nosso [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour#:%7E:text=Stack%20Overflow%20em%20Portugu%C3%AAs%20%C3%A9,para%20cada%20pergunta%20sobre%20programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o.):

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para
> programadores profissionais e entusiastas. É construído e administrado
> por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de perguntas e
> respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para desenvolver
> uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta sobre
> programação.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String Texto = "Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas. É construído e administrado por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de perguntas e respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para desenvolver uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta sobre programação.";
        
        //Substitui todas as ocorrências de "respostas" por "soluções"
        System.out.println(Texto.replaceAll("respostas", "soluções"));
        //Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e soluções para 
        //programadores profissionais e entusiastas. É construído e 
        //administrado por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de 
        //perguntas e soluções. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para 
        //desenvolver uma biblioteca de soluções detalhadas para cada pergunta 
        //sobre programação.
        
        //Substitui apenas a primeira ocorrências de "respostas" por "soluções"
        System.out.println(Texto.replaceFirst("respostas", "soluções"));
        //Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e soluções para 
        //programadores profissionais e entusiastas. É construído e 
        //administrado por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de 
        //perguntas e respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para 
        //desenvolver uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta 
        ///sobre programação.
        
    }
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDE.One](https://ideone.com/RxytVF)</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar o replace:

###### Str.replace('', '')

```
##Example##

String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");

System.out.print("Return Value :" );
System.out.println(Str.replace('o', 'T'));

System.out.print("Return Value :" );
System.out.println(Str.replace('l', 'D'));
```

---

```
##Output##

Return Value :WelcTme tT TutTrialspTint.cTm
Return Value :WeDcome to TutoriaDspoint.com
```

---

##### FONTE

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm